# Read.table error: the first field contains the column delimiter, so too many columns are read

Tags: r, read.table

As reading R cookbook, I copied data from the PDF file and pasted it into a file named suburbs.txt. Then in R I used the following code to input the data.

```
read.table("suburbs.txt",header=TRUE)
```

But I got

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 8 did not have 5 elements`
```

What I expected was

```
cat("city county state pop\n Arlington Heights Cook IL 76031\n", file="s1.txt")`

read.table("s1.txt",header=TRUE)
```

I checked line 8 in suburbs.txt and found out that the city column in line 8 was Arlington Heights which had 2 words, and the rest of other lines in city column had only 1 word. It seemed R did not recognise this and caused the mistake.

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: One must assume that spaces cannot occur in other fields.  In that case, you could (with sed, e.g.) easily rewrite the file to change the field separators to another character.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out with your help.

Comment: You may answer your own question.